# pandas dataframe 0 become scientific notation. PL

Tags: python, excel, pandas

assume one cell has -1449.07, another one has 1449.07 when you add them it should be 0, but instead it become somethinglike 1.4210854715202E-13
or like -5.82076609134674E-11 which are extremly close to 0.

and this happens for the entire dataframe, for some of the 0s.

I have tried do use round(2), set_options...none of them works.

I used dd = pd.DataFrame(need_group.groupby(['A','B'])['balance'].sum()) to add the values

someone please help!!!!

Comment: Why don't you do: `dd = pd.DataFrame(need_group.groupby(['A','B'])['balance'].sum()).round(2)`?

Comment: @pavel Thanks for your answer. but is it the same if I do dd.round(2) after dd = pd.DataFrame(need_group.groupby(['A','B'])['balance'].sum())   will this make any difference?

Comment: Could you give a short example of a need_group to reproduce the behaviour?